# Using named range in VBA function for VLOOKUP

Tags: vba, excel, range, vlookup

I have a the following on my worksheet:

- A cell that shows a currency [in `A1`]
- A range of cells (two columns, one for the currency, and the other for a corresponding commission percentage) [defined as/named `RANGE`, and scoped to the worksheet]
- A cell that [is trying] to determine the calculated commission percentage based on `A1` and `RANGE`

I then have a VBA function called `Calculate`, as follows:

```vb
Function Calculate(LookupValue As Double, LookupRange As Range) As Double
    Calculate = [VLOOKUP(LookupValue, LookupRange, 2)]
End Function
```

The cell that determines the percentage has the following:

```
=Calculate(A1, RANGE)
```

Problem is that the cell just returns `#VALUE!`...

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

I have tried several things like type-hinting to `Range()`, passing `LookupRange.Value2` to `VLOOKUP`, etc, none of which worked.

I have also tried to debug, noting that `LookupRange` does actually contain the range required in `Value2`, which is is why I tried to pass it to the function.

***Side Note:*** The function and layout mentioned above is just a dummy - the actual function is somewhat more complex as it relies on negotiated rates, monthly margins, etc. This is why I'm using VBA in the first place. I know that I'm doing something wrong with the lookup, as it is the only thing that seems to be failing within the function - everything else corresponds and calculates.

Comment: get rid of the `[]` which returns a range object. There is no range called _whatever your lookup returns_. You want to return the value: `Calculate = `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP(LookupValue, LookupRange, 2)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

> The advantage of using square brackets is that the code is shorter. The advantage of using `Evaluate` is that the argument is a string, so you can either construct the string in your code or use a Visual Basic variable.

in other words you **can** use

```
Calculate = [VLOOKUP(3, A1:B100, 2)]
```

but you **can not** use

```
LookupValue = 3
LookupRange = Range("A1:B100")
'or
'LookupRange = "A1:B100"
Calculate = [VLOOKUP(LookupValue, LookupRange, 2)]
```

What you can do is:

**Option 1:**

```
Function Calculate(LookupValue As Double, LookupRange As Range) As Double
    Calculate = Evaluate("VLOOKUP(" & LookupValue & "," & LookupRange.Address & ", 2")
End Function
```

or better:

```
Function Calculate(LookupValue As Double, LookupRange As Range) As Double
    Calculate = Evaluate("VLOOKUP(" & LookupValue & ",'" & _
        LookupRange.Parent.Name & "'!" & LookupRange.Address & ", 2")
End Function
```

However I suggest:

**Option 2:**

```
Function Calculate(LookupValue As Double, LookupRange As Range) As Double
    Calculate = Application.VLookup(LookupValue, LookupRange, 2)
End Function
```

I hope you know about meaning of [4th parameter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx):

> If `TRUE` or omitted, an exact or approximate match is returned. If an exact match is not found, the next largest value that is less than lookup_value is returned.
>   The values in the first column of table_array must be placed in ascending sort order; otherwise, `VLOOKUP` may not give the correct value. You can put the values in ascending order by choosing the Sort command from the Data menu and selecting Ascending.

Btw, `Calculate` is not good name for UDF, since VBA already has function `Application.Calculate`. I'd rename it to avoid confusion.

Comment: +1 for the importance of the 4th parameter. I have seen so many times where this is omitted and people want to know why it doesn't work the way they expect.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a ton :) Option 2 worked for me... I tried somthing similar to that when I was doing the rounds, and it still returned a `#VALUE`, but I may have missed something there... Anyway, it works now. (I'm a VBA newbie trying to sort out something for a client - so much appreciated.) :)

Comment: Oh, and yes, I'm aware of the 4th parameter - I need to be approximated in my case. Many thanks again :)